# typescript can I access to the callback parameters

Tags: typescript

Is there a possibility to get callback parameters in 'outer' function?

```
function f(callback: (par1: string)=>void): void {
  // can I get here 'par1'?  
}
```

Comment: No you can't ... Because when the body of the "outer" function is executed, the callback isn't even called yet ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function f(callback: (par1: string)=>void): void {
  // can I get here 'par1'?  
}
```

No, because it's `f` who is responsible for calling that callback function. There's no value associated to that parameter. It's the job of your function `f` to pass that value while calling it.

```
function f(callback: (par1: string)=>void): void {
      callback("1"); //callback is called with value "1"
      callback("hello world"); //callback is called with value "hello world"
}
```